# Difference between SchemaUpdate and SchemaExport in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

What is the difference between SchemaUpdate and SchemaExport in Hibernate.

[SchemaUpdate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaUpdate.html)

[SchemaExport](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*SchemaExport* (aka hbm2ddl) is tool that generates database schema (whole, not partial) from Hibernate mappings. SchemaExport needs to aware of dialect, but it does not consult existing database. Generated DDL statements can then be executed and/or saved to file and/or printer to standard out.

*SchemaUpdate* updates existing schema. To some extent it figures out which DDL statement should be executed to make existing database match to modified Hibernate mappings.

Good source for more detailed information is [Hibernate Core Reference Manual - Chapter 22. Toolset Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/toolsetguide.html).

Comment: For NHibernate, *SchemaUpdate* will create the schema if it doesn't already exist and update the existing schema if required and desired. It is my understanding that for Hibernate this is also true.